# Applying styles for DatePicker - MUI react

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, mui-x-date-picker

I want to add DatePicker to my site from MUI X. I also want to add my own styles. Replace border-color, remove border-radius, change text and label color to white. (screenshot of the design below). I realized that many people face difficulty in styling components. I tried using sx, I accessed the elements through classes directly.

```
"& label": {
              color: "white",
            },
```

But when I tried to change the border-color strange things started to happen. When I hovered over the component, the border-color became black. Sometimes all the styles disappeared, as if I had not specified them. As a result, I want to know how to apply styles to MUI components and DatePicker in particular.

As I said above, I tried using sx and accessing the classes directly

```
<DatePicker
      label="Date"
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={handleDateChange}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      sx={{
        "& label": {
          color: "white",
        },
        "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "yellow",
        },
        ".Mui-focused": {
          "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "red",
          },
        },
        ".css-1l0x3a7-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root .MuiOutlinedInput-root fieldset": {
          borderColor: "green",
        },
        ".css-1jy569b-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused": {
          color: "white",
        },
        ".MuiSvgIcon-root": {
          color: "white",
        },
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Please share a code which you've tried. So, we can look into it and help you out.

Comment: I dont think sx prop will work like this at root level. You will have to pass these as per the slots provided. If you are trying to apply these changes to the textfield then you will have to use slotProps and inside that the textField and in it's sx prop you will have to change